# Test for correlation between continuous and categorical variable

Tags: correlation, categorical-data

I am wanting to know what type of statistical test would need to be carried out to determine if there is a correlation between one categorical variable and one continuous variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what categorical variable are we talking about? Is it binomial (male, female) or ordinal (small bigger big large). It would be wrong to check correlation of variables that are binomial, but you could use a t-test. If it is ordinal than your best chance would be probably Spearman rank test.

Comment: the two variables are knowledge (numerical, continuous) and years of experience (categorical, ordinal)